# How do I code out with numeric keypads with multi textboxes?

Tags: vb.net, button, textbox

I'm trying to code out a programme where the user sees a form and in that form, there are 2 text boxes and 10 buttons.

```
Username: 
Password: 
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
  0
```

I've tried this code

```
Private Sub Btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn1.Click
    If UsernameTextbox.Focused = True Then
        UsernameTextbox.Text = UsernameTextbox.Text + "1"
    End If
End Sub
```

I understand that clicking on Btn1 will steal the focus from the text box. So how can I write the programme?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to declare a variable of type `Control` and, in the `Leave` event handler for each control, assign the `sender` to that variable. You can then use that variable in the `Click` event handler of your `Button` to determine which control had focus and possibly reassign back to that control and then update it appropriately. You can do the lot with two event handlers, e.g.

```
Private previouslyActiveTextBox As TextBox

Private Sub TextBoxes_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.Leave,
                                                                      TextBox1.Leave
    previouslyActiveTextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
End Sub

Private Sub Buttons_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click,
                                                                    Button2.Click,
                                                                    Button1.Click
    previouslyActiveTextBox.Select()
    previouslyActiveTextBox.SelectedText = CStr(DirectCast(sender, Button).Tag)
End Sub
```

That code handles multiple events with a single method in both cases. It also requires that you assign the number for each `Button` to the `Tag` property of that control. Note that it also sets the `SelectedText`, rather than appending to the `Text` property. That is more correct because it will add the new text where the caret is actually located and replace text if it is selected.

An even better option might be to use a custom button control that doesn't take focus. Here's one I prepared earlier:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?459890-Building-Blocks-for-an-On-screen-Keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Items within a ToolStrip do not *grab* focus when clicked.  While the standard ToolStrip usage is as a menu bar, there is nothing that prevents you from using it as a container for buttons laid out in a grid.  In fact, the class [ToolStrip.LayoutStyle Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.layoutstyle?view=netframework-4.8) allows you select a table style.

The following is a proof-of-concept custom ToolStrip that is prepopulated with the buttons to create a number pad like control.  The control has sufficient function to work as intended, but is not locked down to prevent misuse by manipulating the Items collection and other properties.

```
Public Class NumPadToolstrip : Inherits ToolStrip

  Private _ButtonSize As Size = New Size(50, 50)
  Private _ButtonMargin As Padding = New Padding(5)
  Private _ButtonBackColor As Color = Color.Ivory

  Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New
    LayoutStyle = ToolStripLayoutStyle.Table
    Dim settings As TableLayoutSettings = CType(LayoutSettings, TableLayoutSettings)
    settings.ColumnCount = 3
    settings.RowCount = 4
    AddButtons(7, 9)
    AddButtons(4, 6)
    AddButtons(1, 3)
    AddButtons(0, 0)
    Dock = DockStyle.None
    AutoSize = True
    BackColor = Color.LightGray
  End Sub

  Public Property ButtonSize As Size
    Get
      Return _ButtonSize
    End Get
    Set(value As Size)
      If value <> _ButtonSize Then
        _ButtonSize = value
        UpdateButtonSizes()
      End If
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Property ButtonMargin As Padding
    Get
      Return _ButtonMargin
    End Get
    Set(value As Padding)
      If value <> _ButtonMargin Then
        _ButtonMargin = value
        UpdateMargins()
      End If
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Property ButtonBackColor As Color
    Get
      Return _ButtonBackColor
    End Get
    Set(value As Color)
      If value <> _ButtonBackColor Then
        _ButtonBackColor = value
        UpdateButtonBackColor()
      End If
    End Set
  End Property

  Private Sub AddButtons(start As Int32, [end] As Int32)
    For num As Int32 = start To [end]
      Dim b As New ToolStripButton With {.Text = num.ToString(),
                                         .Size = ButtonSize,
                                         .Margin = ButtonMargin,
                                         .BackColor = ButtonBackColor,
                                         .AutoSize = False}

      AddHandler b.Paint, Sub(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs)
                            With e.Graphics
                              Dim r As Rectangle = e.ClipRectangle
                              r.Inflate(-1, -1)
                              r.Location = Point.Empty
                              .DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, r)
                            End With
                          End Sub


      Items.Add(b)
    Next
  End Sub

  Private Sub UpdateButtonSizes()
    SuspendLayout()
    For Each btn As ToolStripButton In Items.OfType(Of ToolStripButton)
      btn.Size = _ButtonSize
    Next
    ResumeLayout()
  End Sub

  Private Sub UpdateMargins()
    SuspendLayout()
    For Each btn As ToolStripButton In Items.OfType(Of ToolStripButton)
      btn.Margin = _ButtonMargin
    Next
    ResumeLayout()
  End Sub

  Private Sub UpdateButtonBackColor()
    SuspendLayout()
    For Each btn As ToolStripButton In Items.OfType(Of ToolStripButton)
      btn.BackColor = _ButtonBackColor
    Next
    ResumeLayout()
  End Sub

End Class
```

Add the above class to your project and perform a build operation.  The NumPadToolstrip control should then be available in the ToolBox.  Add the control to the form and then add a handler for its `ItemClicked` event to pass the proper text to the TextBox.

```
Private Sub NumPadToolstrip1_ItemClicked(sender As Object, e As ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs) Handles NumPadToolstrip1.ItemClicked
  Dim tb As TextBoxBase = TryCast(ActiveControl, TextBoxBase)
  If tb IsNot Nothing Then tb.SelectedText = e.ClickedItem.Text
End Sub
```